# JQuery UI Sortable - Cousin elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible rearrange cousin elements using JQuery UI Sortable?

Given:

```
<div>
    <div id="parent1">
        <div id="something1"></div>
        <div id="sortable-item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="parent2">
        <div class="something2"></div>
        <div id="sortable-item2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected Result after rearranging elements using JQuery UI Sortable (#sortable-item1 and #sortable-item2):

```
<div>
    <div id="parent1">
        <div id="something1"></div>
        <div id="sortable-item2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="parent2">
        <div class="something2"></div>
        <div id="sortable-item1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `cousin elements`?

Comment: Elements with parents that are siblings. In the example, the cousin elements are the two 'divs' with the class 'sortable-item'

Comment: What do you mean by rearranging? Could you please post an example of your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Absolutely possible, try this code.

```
 $(function() {
 $( "#parent1,#parent2" ).sortable({connectWith: "#parent1, #parent2"}).disableSelection();
```

});